# PHP Regex match between two patterns

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to parse through a log file containing numerous traces, some of which have multiple lines to them.

Example:

```
[trace-123] <request>This is a log line</request>
[trace-124] <reply>This is another log line

this is part of "[trace-124]" still.</reply>
[trace-125] <request>final log line.</request>
```

I'm attempting to use preg_match_all to get an array of all the traces.

```
$file = file_get_contents("traces.txt");
$tracePattern = "/(\[trace-[0-9]*+\]+[\s\S]*)(?<=\<\/reply>|\<\/request>)/";

preg_match_all($tracePattern,$file,$lines);

echo "<pre>";print_r($lines);echo "</pre>";
```

Ideally, I'd like my results to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [trace-123] <request>This is a log line</request>
    [1] => [trace-124] <reply>This is another log line

this is part of "[trace-124]" still.</reply>
    [2] => [trace-125] <request>final log line.</request>
)
```

but when I run it, I get an array with everything in 1 element of the array. When I wrote the expression, my goal was to basically look for:

```
[trace-\[0-9]*\]
```

and find everything from that match to the next match of it.

I found that

```
\[trace-[0-9]*+\].*
```

works pretty well, but breaks down when there are line breaks.

Comment: I fail to see why what you are doing would require regex at all.  You can simply loop through each line of the file looking for `[trace-` at the beginning of the string.  Each time you encounter this value, start adding the lines to a string at the next array position in teh array you are building.  You stop adding to this string the next time you encounter either another line beginning with `[trace-` or the next time you encounter a line beginning with some other non-trace signature (like for instance if you have lines like `[error-` or whatever).

Comment: To contiune my comment... requiring multi-line regex is likely going to require you put put your ENTIRE log file into memory (either that or at least store portions of it into memory until next `[trace-` is seen, which basically requires the implementation I suggested above to be to execute). This may not be feasible for larger log files.  You likely should focus on a solution that allows you to parse and work with a single line at a time.

Comment: @Mike - With multi-gig ram capacity, if a file is too big. reading line by line might take a protracted period of time and building an array would have to be offloaded as well. Another approach would be read in 10,000 lines at a time, process records with a multi-line regex, capture the last record start, put at front of buffer, read another 10,000 lines (or, like 10 megs), repeat.

Comment: @sin True, but oftentimes you want a very process that is very light on RAM, as the servers may be taking production load.  In these cases, you cannot afford to dedicate large chunks of RAM to a single process.  You are right that building the array might be too expensive on RAM as well depending on number of overall lines where this trace data is present.

Comment: @Mike - Yeah thats true, but in a server environment each virtual machine might be given a gig or two virtual ram. But thats a lot of disk seeks doing it line by line on partitioned drives. Reading in 10 meg chunks and using a multi-line regex is a good balance when it comes to resources. Flat out, its at least 10 or more times faster.

Comment: Is there any benefit to just reading the file size and using that to determine whether I should go line by line or read the whole file into RAM at once? 

I assume with a smaller file, it makes more sense to just load it all into ram, but in a larger file it may make more sense to read it in chunks. I'm not sure how to read it in chunks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would probably be a better approach here.

```
$results = preg_split('/\R(?=\[trace[^\]]*\])/', $text);
print_r($results);
```

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/68243)

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => [trace-123] <request>This is a log line</request>
    [1] => [trace-124] <reply>This is another log line

this is part of "[trace-124]" still.</reply>
    [2] => [trace-125] <request>final log line.</request>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$file = '[trace-123] <request>This is a log line</request>
[trace-124] <reply>This is another log line

this is part of "[trace-124]" still.</reply>
[trace-125] <request>final log line.</request>';

$tracePattern = "/\[trace-[0-9]*+\]+\s*<(?:reply|request)>.*?<\/(?:reply|request)>/s";

preg_match_all($tracePattern,$file,$lines);

$lines = $lines[0]; // by defaults, $lines[0] will be an array of the matches, so get that

echo "<pre>";print_r($lines);echo "</pre>";
```

Working demo: http://ideone.com/n8n5r3

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a solution via `preg_split`

```
preg_split('/\R+(?=\[trace-\d+])/', $str)
```

this results in the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => [trace-123] <request>This is a log line</request>
    [1] => [trace-124] <reply>This is another log line

this is part of "[trace-124]" still.</reply>
    [2] => [trace-125] <request>final log line.</request>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in MULTI_LINE mode. Trims leading spaces and trailing newline's.

Edit: This assumes an anchor that is `[trace- ]` and is either at the beginning of
the line or beginning plus non-newline whitespace until 'trace'. This is the
only discernable record separator.

```
 #  ^[^\S\n]*(\[trace-[^]]*\][^\n]*(?:(?!\s+\[trace-[^]]*\])\n[^\n]*)*)

 ^ [^\S\n]* 
 (
      \[trace- [^]]* \] [^\n]* 

      (?:
           (?! \s+ \[trace- [^]]* \] )
           \n [^\n]* 
      )*
 )
```

Output (in single quotes)

```
 '[trace-123] <request>This is a log line</request>'
 '[trace-124] <reply>This is another log line

 this is part of "[trace-124]" still.</reply>'
 '[trace-125] <request>final log line.</request>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `.` means every char except line breaks `\n`, you can try to change it with `(.|\s)` this way :

```
#\[trace-[0-9]*+\](.|\s)*#
```

Note : you can use non-capturant parenthesis `(?:  )`

Easyer, add the flag "s"

```
#\[trace-[0-9]*+\].*#s
```

Comment: No need, he can add pattern modifier `s` (PCRE_DOTALL).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a reluctant quantifier (`??`, `+?` or `*?`).

I believe this regex `/(\[trace-[0-9]*\]\s*(?m:.*?)<\/(?:reply|request)>)/` should do it... the `(?m:.*?)` part is the secret. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do with the flag `s` on:

```
(\[trace-[0-9]+\].*?<\/(?:reply|request)>)
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wB1dY3)